# PHP code inside Contact form 7 Email template

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

Is there any way to insert PHP code inside `contact form 7` Email Template? I want to make footer copyright year as dynamic in it.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this, as this is considered post content. However, you could write a function to append a copyright to all or specific contact forms.

Comment: @rnevius, Thank you for the information. Could you please help to find out the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible by using the `wpcf7_before_send_mail` hook.

In your functions.php you can use the following code:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_add_text_to_mail_body' );

function wpcf7_add_text_to_mail_body($contact_form){

    // get mail property
    $mail = $contact_form->prop( 'mail' ); // returns array with mail values

    // add date (or other content) to email body
    $mail['body'] .= date('Y');

    // set mail property with changed value(s)
    $contact_form->set_properties( array( 'mail' => $mail ) );

}
```

Comment: how would i do something similar then this but add in the middle of the mail some text with calculation based on what they have selected. 2 user inputs: amount of customers & sector. each sector has a value to it so i was thinking about a case statement of some sort: case sector x then customers * value