# How to add php to wordpress form

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, forms

I'm having a very hard time trying to get a php code integrated into a form I've created on wordpress. I've trying 3 different php plugins to no avail. Here is the html and css. Does anyone have any idea where I should be putting the php on wordpress and how I should properly call it through the "action" in the form?

css:

```
<style>
  input[type=text], input[type=number], select[name=province]{ font-family: arial; width:100%;  
  border: 1px solid #E5E5E5; padding: 10px 20px;}
input[name=ffirstname] {width:49%; margin-right:1%; }
input[name=lastname] {width:49%; margin-left:1%; }
input[name=address] {width:65.6667%; margin-right:1%; }
input[name=unit] {width:32.3337%; margin-left:1%; }
input[name=city] {width:49%; margin-right:1%; }
select[name=province] {width:24%; margin-left:1%;}
input[name=postal] {width:24%; margin-left:1%; }
input[name=email] {width:49%; margin-right:1%; }
input[name=phone] {width:49%; margin-left:1%;}
input[class=submit] {
  background-color: #f05a28;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin-left: 85%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none; !important;
  outline: none; !important ;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: none; !important;
}
</style>
```

html:

```
<form name"infoform" method="post" action="form-to-email.php" >
  <br><input type="text" name="ffirstname" placeholder="First Name"/><input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"/>
  <br><br><input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address"/><input type="text" name="unit" placeholder="Unit"/></br>
  <br><input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City"/><select name="province" form="form1">
<option value="ab">AB</option>
  <option value="BC">BC</option>
  <option value="BC">MB</option>
  <option value="NB">NB</option>
<option value="NL">NL</option>
<option value="NS">NS</option>
<option value="ON">ON</option>
<option value="PE">PE</option>
<option value="QC">QC</option>
<option value="SK">SK</option>
</select><input type="text" name="postal" placeholder="Postal Code"/></br>
<br><input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country"/></br>
<Br><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/><input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="Phone#"/></br>
<br> <br><input type="submit" value="Next"/>
```

php:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['ffirstname'];
$email = $_POST['lastname'];
$message = $_POST['address'];

$to = "joeblow@hotmail.com"; 
$subject = "My contact form";   
$body = " You have received a new";
mail($to,$subject,$body);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually I use `footer.php` to add JS and PHP code, just before the closing tag of the body. But if that does not work try using `header.php`. Maybe your code needs to be included before the end.
The HTML part you can put inside a page or post without a problem.

If you want to use a plug-in, you can easily do that with [Contact form 7](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/).

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924821/php-code-inside-contact-form-7-email-template) and [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-style-contact-form-7-in-wordpress/) for tutorials.

UPDATE - to add PHP code into Wordpress:

You can add the code between `<?php` tags, so open your `header.php`,  `footer.php` or `page.php` and write your code inside the tag

```
<?php

//PHP Code here

?>
```

This way you will see this code in every Wordpress page on your site.

Header and footer are always included on all pages.
If you only need it in post or page use `page.php` or `post.php`

Comment: I dont want to use contact 7 or any other plug-in, I want to be able to format the table very specifically. How do I put the php into the header or footer in wordpress?

Comment: Where can i find these php files exactly in wordpress? Do i go through cpanel and find it in the folders? If so where would it be located.

Comment: there are two way: one by FTP in wp-content -> theme -> files are here. Other inside Wordpress appearance -> Editor -> file in right menu .

Comment: Thank you so much for your help my friend. Can I also create a new php file and upload it for the email submit function?

Comment: Your welcome! yes you can, you need call the new files. If you want use the editor html inside wp you can not use php, you need to enable form functions.php

Comment: hmm..So I created a new file called "formemail.php", and i updated the form in html to call it, however when i submit the form, the page redirects to "page not found 404 error" and i dont get an email of the submission. I wrote the code exactly as i have it above into the php file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want control over the placement of php within a Wordpress page then have a look at [page templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/). You could create a form page template that had the form and the necessary php to deal with it, and then apply that to a given url e.g. `/sign-up`. That way you wouldn't have to have the form code cluttering up the `header.php` or `footer.php` of every page.

With the form itself, you could just have it `post` to itself, and then check to see whether the form variables are set when the page is loaded using `isset($_POST['field_name'])`. If they're present then you can assume the form was posted, and you need to therefore send the email, otherwise if they're not present then you can assume you need to display the form.

e.g.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['ffirstname'])){ 
    // Do some appropriate sanitization for your use case 
    $ffirstname = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['ffirstname']));
    //.. repeat for other fields, and then send email
    // could drop out of php here and show a thank you message
    ?>
    <p>Thank you for submitting the form</p>
    <?php
} else {
   // $_POST['ffirstname'] not set, so show form ?>
   <form method="post" action="">
       <input type="text" name="ffirstname" />
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
<?php } ?>
```

If you want to hook into Wordpress for this, then one way to do it is to add a hidden input called action and set its value to the name of a function in your `functions.php` file. You'll also need to add some javascript to make an ajax submission to the function that could then do the logic and email sending:

e.g.

```
// Form Page
<form method="post" action="" id="emailForm">
    <input type="text" name="ffirstname" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="sendEmail" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

// Somewhere further down the same page as the form
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#emailForm').on('submit', function() {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data: jQuery('#emailForm').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                // Perhaps some UI update here to let the user know 
                // the submission was successful
            },
            error: function(error) {
                // Do something with the error 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then in your themes `functions.php` file:

```
// Functions.php
function sendEmail(){
    // Do some appropriate sanitization for your use case 
    $ffirstname = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['ffirstname']));
    //.. repeat for other fields as necessary, and then send email
    return wp_mail($recipient, $subject, $body, $headers);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_sendEmail', 'sendEmail');
```